# Java Swing/AWT gui formatting

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am just learning Java GUIs, and about layout managers and am looking to create a GUI with the following layout. What would be the best way to approach this? (`JFrame` is 1000w x 800h)

Here is what I've thought of doing with some success, and a messy solution that doesn't match the wanted layout **exactly**

```
JFrame myFrame (GridLayout(2,1))
    - JPanel topPanel (BorderLayout)
        - JPanel topLeftPanel (GridLayout(9,2) & setSize 666,400)
            - JLabel buyingAnInvestment      - Jlabel empty1
            - JLabel type                    - JComboBox typeSelect
            - JLabel symbol                  - JTextField symbolField
            - JLabel empty2                  - JLabel empty3
            - JLabel name                    - JTextField nameField
            - JLabel empty4                  - JLabel empty5
            - JLabel quantity                - JTextField quantityField
            - JLabel empty6                  - JLabel epty7
            - JLabel price                   - JTextField price
        - JPanel topRightPanel (GridLayout(2,1) & setSize 333,400)
            - JButton reset
            - JButton buy
    - JPanel bottomPanel (What should I do for this?)
        - JLabel messages
        - JTextArea & JScrollArea
```

How would you layout the components and `JPanel` containers to get the expected result? Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, there's at least two `BorderLayout`s and at least one `GridBagLayout`, I'd be tempted to use a second for the buttons, but that's me

Answer (score 2):

If the GUI can have `Buying an investment` & `Messages` as a `TitledBorder`, I'd lay it out as follows:

- Outer layout - `BorderLayout`

  1. `Buying an investment` using a two column `GridBagLayout` of labels and fields. Put it in the `CENTER` of the border layout.
  2. `Reset` / `Buy` buttons in a single column `GridLayout` with an ample `EmptyBorder` and vertical layout padding. Put that panel in the `LINE_END` of the border layout.
  3. The text area insinde a panel / constraint that will stretch it to full width & height E.G. using another `GridLayout` in the `PAGE_END` of the border layout.

> (`JFrame` is 1000w x 800h)

Don't try to guess the size the GUI needs. Layout all the components, then `pack()` the frame. The GUI will become the smallest size it needs in order to display everything it contains.

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly an elaboration of @AndrewThompson's answer.
The changes and simplifications as compared to your original approach are:

- No explicit `setSize` calls. Instead let the layout-managers choose
  the sizes when `pack()` is called on the `JFrame`
  and when the user resizes it.
- There are only 3 panels (as `CENTER`, `EAST` and `SOUTH` part
  in a `BorderLayout`).
- The headings "Buy an investment" and "Messages" are implemented as
  `TitledBorder`, not as `JLabel`.
- Using `GridBagLayout`instead of `GridLayout`, because then you
  have much better control by using proper [`GridBagConstraints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html)
  (especially `fill`, `anchor`, `weightx`, `weighty`, `insets`).

[image: screenshot]

The above layout was produced by following code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::initGUI);
    }

    private static void initGUI() {
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Investment Portfolio");
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel topLeftPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        myFrame.add(topLeftPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        topLeftPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Buying an investment"));
        GridBagConstraints labelConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        labelConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        labelConstraints.gridx = 0;
        labelConstraints.gridy = 0;
        labelConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        labelConstraints.weighty = 1;
        labelConstraints.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10);
        GridBagConstraints fieldConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        fieldConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        fieldConstraints.gridx = 1;
        fieldConstraints.gridy = 0;
        fieldConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        fieldConstraints.weighty = 1;
        fieldConstraints.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10);
        topLeftPanel.add(new JLabel("Type"), labelConstraints);
        JComboBox<String> typeSelect = new JComboBox<>(new String[] { "stock", "aaaaaaaa" });
        topLeftPanel.add(typeSelect, fieldConstraints);
        labelConstraints.gridy++;
        topLeftPanel.add(new JLabel("Symbol"), labelConstraints);
        JTextField symbolField = new JTextField(10);
        fieldConstraints.gridy++;
        topLeftPanel.add(symbolField, fieldConstraints);
        labelConstraints.gridy++;
        topLeftPanel.add(new JLabel("Name"), labelConstraints);
        JTextField nameField = new JTextField(20);
        fieldConstraints.gridy++;
        topLeftPanel.add(nameField, fieldConstraints);
        labelConstraints.gridy++;
        topLeftPanel.add(new JLabel("Quantity"), labelConstraints);
        JTextField quantityField = new JTextField(6);
        fieldConstraints.gridy++;
        topLeftPanel.add(quantityField, fieldConstraints);
        labelConstraints.gridy++;
        topLeftPanel.add(new JLabel("Price"), labelConstraints);
        JTextField priceField = new JTextField(6);
        fieldConstraints.gridy++;
        topLeftPanel.add(priceField, fieldConstraints);

        JPanel topRightPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        topRightPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        myFrame.add(topRightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        GridBagConstraints buttonConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        buttonConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        buttonConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        buttonConstraints.weighty = 1;
        buttonConstraints.gridy = 0;
        JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
        topRightPanel.add(reset, buttonConstraints);
        JButton buy = new JButton("Buy");
        buttonConstraints.gridy++;
        topRightPanel.add(buy, buttonConstraints);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        myFrame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        bottomPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Messages"));
        JTextArea messagesArea = new JTextArea(6, 30);
        bottomPanel.add(new JScrollPane(messagesArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```